# How can I make lcms available to imageinfo (via imagemagick)?

Tags: imagemagick

When I try to run:

```
imageinfo --iccname test.jpg
```

I get the following error:

```
imageinfo: installed imagemagick does not support lcms
```

Even though ImageMagick (6.6.2-6) is set-up to use lcms:

```
DELEGATES     bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype gvc jpeg jng jp2 lcms lqr openexr png rsvg tiff x11 xml wmf zlib
LIBS          -lMagickCore -llcms -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -llqr-1 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread -lltdl
```

(output from convert -list configure | grep 'DELEGATES\|LIBS')

Any ideas how to make it work, if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was that I have previously built imagemagick from source (and forgot about it), so when I ran `convert -list configure | grep 'DELEGATES\|LIBS'` it was showing output from imagemagick installed from repositories while `imageinfo --iccname test.jpg` was using imagemagick that I built from source which did not have lcms support.